# Not able to downloade multiple images at same time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my program i am downloading a Json array file contating data of notices. Each notice contain an address field from  where senders image is to be downloaded. So I run another async task to download the  images for each json array object. But only 1st image is downloaded no matter how many element json array has. I even tried executeOnExecutor but only folders were created and no images were downloaded.

The onpostexecute method is as below

```
      @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);

                try {

                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        // refining the notices sent by server
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("notices");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonArrayChild = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Retrieving data for each notice item
                            String name = jsonArrayChild.optString("name");
                            String heading = jsonArrayChild.optString("heading");
                            String date = jsonArrayChild.optString("date");
                            String noticeContent = jsonArrayChild
                                    .optString("content");
                            imageaddress = jsonArrayChild.optString("image");

                            imageName = imageaddress.substring(
                                    imageaddress.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                                    imageaddress.length());

                            // first we need to download the image from location
                            // specified in string imageaddress

                            new ProcessDownloadNoticeSenderImage()
                                    .execute(imageaddress);

                            // now inserting the overall data into database
                            // storing the local address of downloaded image in
                            // database
                            File file = new File(
                                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                            + "/veda/images/" + imageName);

                            String localImageAddress = file.getAbsolutePath();

                            // storing data in database
                            noticeMainDatabase.insertNotice(name, heading, date,
                                    noticeContent, localImageAddress);
                            // first we need to download the image from location
                            // specified in string imageaddress

                        }
               }
    }
```

and ProcessDownloadNoticeSenderImage is as below

```
private class ProcessDownloadNoticeSenderImage extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/veda/images");

            boolean success = false;

            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdir();
            }
            if (success) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "veda/images folder is successfully created to store the images",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // saving the downloaded image into folder
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "/veda/images/" + imageName);
            if (f.exists()) {
                FileOutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        out.close();
                    } catch (Throwable ignore) {

                    }
                }
            } else if (!f.exists()) {
                FileOutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        out.close();
                    } catch (Throwable ignore) {

                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                bitmap = downloadImageFromServer(params[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

    }
```

help me in how to download multiple images so that i can show them in list.

Comment: Did you try to confirm that `ProcessDownloadNoticeSenderImage` executes as many times as the number of images?? Try to put a Log in the `doBackground` and check it

Comment: its executing more then one time but the image i.e downloaded is only first

Comment: as per the code Bitmap is initialized null and is written out to file and then downloaded?? am i missing something here??